# time capsule network using snow leopard laptop as a router

Tags: macos, internet-connection, time-capsule

My cable modem went south today, and my ISP can't do the service call until Wednesday.  I am attempting to temporarily get my network working, with minimal changes to the infrastructure, to go out through my tethered iPhone.

Here is the setup I am trying:

MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard tethering via USB to my iPhone (this works, the laptop can connect to the internet without issue).

Time capsule connected to the MacBok Pro via Ethernet with the MacBook Pro sharing the USB iPhone with ethernet.  This step doesn't work.

The issue I am running into is getting the network settings right on the Time Capsule box.

Looking at the MacBook Pro network settings I see that it is sharing via: 196.254.100.220
I am at a loss for the settings to put into the Time Capsule box for:

IP Address, Subnet Mask, and Router Address, or if I can even get this to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you've connect the WAN port (the one with the "circle of dots" icon) of your Time Capsule to your MacBook Pro, and set your Time Capsule to be in "Create a Network" (wireless AP mode) and "Share a single IP address" (NAT and DHCP) mode.

That way your Time Capsule will get its IP address from the DHCP server that runs on your MacBook Pro when your MacBook Pro is in Internet Sharing mode.